# Check if file exists in the JList

Tags: java, file, jlist

I have added a few files in my JList from the JFileChooser. I am adding a new button named "CHECK" which when clicked, tells if a particular file exists in the JList(among the files already added). It would be really great if any of you could tell me what is the correct procedure to do this step.

Thanking You in Advance..

This is my code currently;

```
            final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    getContentPane().add(fileChooser, "cell 0 0 3 9");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "cell 10 1 3 8,grow");

    vector = new Vector<File>();
    final JList list = new JList(vector);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel, "cell 3 4 7 1,grow");

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add Files");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (File file : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                        vector.add(file);
                        System.out.println("Added..!!");
                }
                list.updateUI();

            }
    });
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Remove Files");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(list.getSelectedIndices().length > 0) {
                  int[] selectedIndices = list.getSelectedIndices();
                  for (int i = selectedIndices.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                        vector.removeElementAt(i);
                        System.out.println("Removed..!!");
                  } 
                   }
                    list.updateUI();

        }   
        });
    panel.add(btnNewButton_1);

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Check For Files");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = "";
            if(list.getSelectedIndices().length > 0 ) {
                       //// to check if a file exists /////
            }
            }
             });

    panel.add(btnNewButton_2);
```

Comment: `if(file.isExists())` is not working ?

Comment: But this just checks if a file exists or not, in general..I would like to know if a file exists or not in the JList which already has some files ih, coz I have added them at the first step.

Comment: It's difficult for us to help without showing some code. Can you post what you've tried/have so far?

Comment: I have added my current code. Kindly check it out..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Vector has a contains method which you can use:

```
if(vector.contains(file)){
   //Vector has the file
}
```

Comment: I think that this could be possible only if File doesn't contains full Path, only FileName or contains String value instead of File

Comment: Yes..You are right. I am able to check the existence..But in that case, I ahve to specify the entire path as an input and what if I dont know the path where it is present? for instance, i am specifying like; File file = new File("H:\\abc.txt");
             if(vector.contains(file)){---}

Answer (score 1):

1. Kindly use the Collections Framework's `List` for the var types and `ArrayList` for the concrete class to instantiate. `Vector` has been a thing of the past since Java 1.2.
2. Iterate over the selected files checking canonical paths at both ends:

```
final File toCheck = fileToCheckInList.getCanonicalFile();
for (File file : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles())
  if (file.getCanonicalFile().equals(toCheck)) return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But even in this case, I ahve to specify the path and only then it checks correctly for existence. what if i dont know the path(path of the file) before?

Comment: We're now getting into the specifics you didn't provide details for. Exactly what string are you using to search for, and exactly what strings are there in the list? (when I say strings, I use it loosely, I know you have Files in there).

Comment: I have several files like zip files and xml files in my JList. I add 3 files in total, 2 xml files are one hex file, out of which I would want to search if a particular xml file exists.

Comment: No, give us an example of the specific strings you use to construct those files or, more generally, strings that calling `toString` on them would produce. Please update your question with those.